# how to find all the possible intersections between two vectors with such organization in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `y` and a vector `x`, I need to find all the possible vectors resulted from the mapping of each value in `x` into each vector in  `y`.

That is difficult to be understood; let's explain is with an example:
Here is an example,   I have the vector `x = [0.7 + 0.7i; 0.7-0.7i];`  The matrix `y = [1 0; 2 0; 1 2];` the resulted matrix is supposed to be like this one `Z = [0.7 + 0.7i 0; 0.7-0.7i 0; 0 0.7 + 0.7i;  0 0.7-0.7i; 0.7 + 0.7i  0.7 + 0.7i; 0.7 + 0.7i  0.7-0.7i; 0.7 - 0.7i  0.7-0.7i ; 0.7 - 0.7i  0.7+0.7i];` . That  is equivalent into `Z = [x_1 0; x_2 0; 0 x_1; 0 x_2; x_1 x_1; x_1 x_2; x_2 x_2; x_2 x_1];`. That means it map each value in `x` into the row of `Z` according to the index  value in `y`.

Here is my try code:
clear all; clc;

```
y = [];
G = 2; 
v = 1 : G; 
for i = 1: G
    x=nchoosek(v,i);
    m = zeros(size(x,1),G-i);
y =[y ; x m];              % creat the matrix y 
end

x = [0.7 + 0.7i; 0.7-0.7i]; 

Z = []; s = zeros(G,1); 
for k=1:size(x,1)
for i=1:size(y,1) 
n=y(i,:);
n=n(n ~= 0);
s(n)=x(k); 
Z=[Z s];
s = zeros(G,1);
end
end
```

The problem in my code that matrix `Z` show the inverse, it means it takes the input `x_1` from `x` and then map it into all possible values in `y`. For example the matrix `Z` starts with  `[x_1 0; 0 x_1; x_1 x_1 ….]`, however that should be the inverse, which means takes each values in `x` and map it as shown in the above example `[x_1 0; x_2 0; x_3 0 …..]`. The second issue, when `y` contains more than non-zeros values, my code cannot get all possible vectors, it can only get `[x_1 x_1; x_2 x_2];` but I cannot map the other possibilities which are `[x_1 x_2; x_2 x_1]` and so on.

How can I solve that issue?

**UPDATE**

[image]

Here is the updated question with clear description. I have the vector `x` and matrix `y`, I need to fill the matrix `z` following the index taken from each row in matrix `y`. For example, if the first row in matrix `y` is `[1 0]` or `[0 1]`; then I will take all possible values from x and put it in `z` following the number taken from the row in `y` which is 1 in this case. Then, the same case for row 2 in matrix `y` which is `[2 0]` or `[0 2]`; it means that second column in z will be filled with all possible values in x.
Then, the two columns in `z` can be filled which is equivalent into the case `[1 2]` in `y`, so it will take the first value from `x` and fill it with all other possible values from `x`, and so on. The rows in `z` should not be repeated.
The matrix `Z` is exactly as shown with below answer of AboAmmar below, but using the loop if with longer vector `x` and bigger matrix `y` will be little bit complicated.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear, the `y` matrix has values 0, 1, 2, how that translates into indices for `x`? Do you skip zeros? If the value in `y` is 1, how do you take x? and if `y` is 2 how to take x? Please clarify.

Comment: @AboAmmar, Each vector in `y` carries the index of the value taken from `x`, for example if the value is 1, the first value of the vector of `y` will be carrying `x`,  and if it's 2, the second value of the vector of `y` will be carrying `x`, in case if both 1 and 2, both will be carrying values from the vector `x` and so on.

Comment: Your example would be simpler if it didn't use complex values, and clearer if the matrices/vectors were formatted to show the rows without relying on interpreting semi-colons of inline code.

Comment: @Wolfie I will rewrite it with a clear way

Comment: @Wolfie I updated the question, I think it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

As you describe it, there are 4 distinct cases for each row of `y` and the corresponding output:

1. `[0 1]` or `[1 0]` => [**x** **0**]
2. `[0 2]` or `[2 0]` => [**0** **x**]
3. `[1 2]` => [x1 x1; x1 x2; x2 x2; x2 x1]
4. `[2 1]` => [x1 x1; x2 x1; x2 x2; x1 x2]

These don't seem to follow any obvious rule. So, the easiest (but not smartest) solution is to use `if-else` and select the suitable case from the above. We don't have all the information about the possible indices, or if rows like `[1 1]` and `[2 2]` might happen, so the following solution is by no means exhaustive; surprising errors might happen if other inputs are fed into `y` matrix.

```
y = [];
G = 2;
v = 1 : G;
for i = 1: G
    x = nchoosek(v,i);
    m = zeros(size(x,1),G-i);
    y = [y ; x m];              % creat the matrix y
end

Z = [];
x = [0.7 + 0.7i; 0.7-0.7i]
for i = 1:size(y,1)
    r = y(i,:);
    if ismember(r, [1 0; 0 1], 'rows')
        Z(end+1:end+2,:) = [x [0; 0]];
    elseif ismember(r, [2 0; 0 2], 'rows')
        Z(end+1:end+2,:) = [[0; 0] x];
    elseif ismember(r, [1 2], 'rows')
        Z(end+1:end+4,:) = [x(1) x(1); x(1) x(2); x(2) x(2); x(2) x(1)];
    elseif ismember(r, [2 1], 'rows')
        Z(end+1:end+4,:) = [x(1) x(1); x(2) x(1); x(2) x(2); x(1) x(2)];
    end
end
```

```
Z =
   0.7000 + 0.7000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.7000 - 0.7000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.7000 + 0.7000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.7000 - 0.7000i
   0.7000 + 0.7000i   0.7000 + 0.7000i
   0.7000 + 0.7000i   0.7000 - 0.7000i
   0.7000 - 0.7000i   0.7000 - 0.7000i
   0.7000 - 0.7000i   0.7000 + 0.7000i
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but if the vector `x` and/or matrix `y` is little bit bigger, that solution will be very difficult to be used. I updated the question and explained what you asked about. I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is valid if you have fix length in `y`, for example if each vector in `y` has one value and others are zeros, or two non-zeros values ...etc.

So you can do your code for each length separately and then build the matrix `Z` by combining all other matrices.